# How to compare two files having slightly different sorting in Linux?

Tags: bash, sorting, comparison

I have two files, say:
File 1:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
```

and File 2:

```
a 1
b 2
d 4
e 5
c 3
f 60
g 70
```

I want the comparing tool to notice that c, d and e lines are just permute each other and not shown them as different. Only f and g are really dissimilar and should be shown.

I have tried tools like Meld, Diffuse or Kompare but they don't help. How can I do that?

This is the file actually and I think simple sort can't help.

```
ATOM     28  OE1 GLN     2      -2.520  35.720  25.080 -0.6086 1.6612
ATOM     29  NE2 GLN     2      -0.770  36.990  25.460 -0.9407 1.8240
ATOM     30 HE21 GLN     2       0.060  37.430  25.080  0.4251 0.6000
ATOM     31 HE22 GLN     2      -1.220  37.300  26.300  0.4251 0.6000
ATOM     32  C   GLN     2      -0.460  35.190  20.480  0.5973 1.9080
ATOM     33  O   GLN     2      -1.520  34.880  19.940 -0.5679 1.6612
```

Comment: Maybe sort both files first and compare then? Will completely destroy the order the lines are in. Is that a problem?

Comment: @ooker: How big are the files? Also, it would be useful to show (some of) both versions of your data file. I'm assuming that the sort solutions don't work because the differences between the lines which have actually changed affects the sortation order, but it needs to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash's [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
diff <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Comment: I have tried this and this doesn't help. Is there another way?

Comment: what is not working? It will work having `file2.txt` and `file2.txt` as you've shown in the question.

Comment: It turns out that the data has already been sort, look at the second column. All I need is sort it as  the other column. Use `sort -k5,5 file.txt` gives me a desired result. Thank you so much.